# How do I communicate between html and node together?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Now the title may seem vague, but being a noob towards node, it's hard to even describe my problem properly.

But I'll describe my question as best as i can.

So i have four files: `index.html`, `script1.js`, `script2.js`.

index.html:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script1.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script2.js is not included within the html, instead it's compiled with the node command `node script2.js`.

Now lets say i compiled the `index.html` along with the `script2.js` (node `script2.js` in my terminal). From here, i want `script2.js` to send data to `script1.js` for it to display the data passed to the HTML.

I think i have to use a server, but i want to try to avoid using it (if that makes sense). How can i do this "locally"?

Thanks and I hope my explanation wasn't too confusing. I'm looking foward to any of your answers!

Comment: Your question is unclear. First of all, JavaScript nor HTML are compiled languages... secondly Node is a runtime environment for JavaScript usually run on the server. You can just use browser JavaScript included in HTML, no need for Node unless you have backend needs

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to achieve what you described without a server. You can run a server by running `node script2.js` if it contains code similar to this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const path = require('path');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', 3000);  
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/get-data', function(req, res) {
  // send data from server to script1.js
});
```

And then when you want to get data from `script1.js` you would do something like this (in `script1.js`):

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/get-data')
  .then(res => { /* do something with data */ })
  .catch(err => { /* handle errors */ });
```

There are ways to achieve this without using express but this one seems easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some function in `script2.js` that can be used by `script1.js` to populate the DOM?

I think what you're looking for is to import `script2.js` into `script1.js`

e.g.

`script1.js` -

```
import * as script2 from 'script2.js' 
// or const script2 = require('script2.js')
// or import { getData } from 'script2.js'

const divtext = script2.getData(); 

var div = document.getElementById('divID');

div.innerHTML += 'Data from script2:' + divtext;
```

`script2.js` -

```
const getData = () => {
  return "This is some info for div"
};

export getData;
```